# Typescript: Define type argument in interface that must implement this interface

Tags: typescript

How can I define such a type:

```js
interface Mappable<To> {
    map(): To
}
```

But then constrain `To` to only accept types that implement `Mappable`. This way you can do something like this:

```js
interface FooMappable extends Mappable<BarMappable>{}
interface BarMappable extends Mappable<FooMappable>{}
function test() {
    val x: FooMappable 
    val y: BarMappable = x.map()
    val z: FooMappable = y.map()
    // etc
    
    val w = Mappable
    w.map().map().map().map()
}
```

The solution shouldn't use `any` since it just escapes the type system.

Comment: `interface Mappable<To extends Mappable<any>>` should be enough.

Comment: Exactly, shown [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLJwA4bgIwDYQA8AKgPbIQAekIAJgM5qbb5FwgCeAfF8gN4AoZMgC2mABQBKAFzIyAbgEBfAQNCRYiFADFSpdFlwEK1CHUYGWBQgCE4US0Yi8+K9dHhJkdh8ycmaBiZDVkJdfT9WFxUYAFcQBDBgUhBkSHowKX4hZAA3e2RKWXDHVmQAXn4lZDhGdg5FYXyoZA5ZH1LjSsoAOjEMKUa8goAvYr1OlG6+iUlFVWFe-qkZgclVleW55QEgA)

Comment: ① You should really add more structure to `FooMappable` and `BarMappable` because right now they're identical and so you missed your bug in the definition of `z`.  ② Assuming you really care about avoiding `any` completely for some reason (the TS type system has both soundness and completeness gaps, so at some point a single `any` isn't going to make things noticeably worse) then you can possibly do something like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mAxp8N) shows.  Does that meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Your solution seems to work well. It also properly catches certain cases of incorrect Mappable typing, unlike the `any` solution which I had used before, which brought to my attention that I had typed some methods incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

You could refactor so that there's a non-[generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) `BaseMappable` interface like this:

```
interface BaseMappable {
  map(): BaseMappable
}
```

which represents your desired constraint directly, and sidesteps the need for recursively-[constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) generic type parameters.  Then your generic `Mappable<T>` can be written like this:

```
interface Mappable<T extends BaseMappable> {
  map(): T;
}
```

Now your example code should still work as desired, even in the face of additional structure for extensions:

```
interface FooMappable extends Mappable<BarMappable> { a: string } // ok
interface BarMappable extends Mappable<FooMappable> { b: number } // ok

function test() {
  var x: FooMappable = {} as any;
  var y: BarMappable = x.map();
  var z: FooMappable = y.map();
  x.map().map().map().map();
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.1.3#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLJwA4bgIwDYQA8AKshAB6QgAmAzsgEJy0Tpa4EB8yA3gFDJkAW0wAKAJQAuZMQDcfAL59QkWIhRMWbbPhT9BIjBOmbWmHQUV9l4aPCTIAYgHtn2jigpU6acx8JMUO663DzIcNK0YFCgAObISip26oxwQX66ZJQQNPTBBIQubhlcvMg40iAArkI40AnWfDBVIAhgwM4gyJBRErwCyABuacjk0kX5KAC8vArh9HAgAJ7ygsNQyEsmaZPIM+QAdIYSq0MjAF7jrrszS0di4qeHx+L3Rq8vbydWQA)